# R CMD Check does not finish the step "Checking PDF version of manual ..."

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, manual

I am creating an R package using R Studio version 0.99.489 together with the most current R development version on Windows 7. I created  documentation .Rd files using roxygen2 and a .Rmd vignette using knitr. Until now everything worked out fine, but when I run the R CMD check within RStudio, the check gets stuck at the step "Checking PDF version of manual ...". I neither get an "OK" nor any error or warnings message. The step just does not proceed, even if I run it over night. I do not get any error or warning messages for the other steps as well, I have "OK"s everywhere.

Consequently, I do not find a PDF manual in the package.Rcheck folder. I already created the manual myself using R CMD Rd2pdf package, which worked out fine. I copied it to several locations within the package folder but this did not help at all.

I searched really a lot but I could not find any solution for this since I do not get any error message. I thought about administration, latex, or R version problems, but I cannot figure out if it is any of those or something else.

One thing I recognized is that when the package is build, it prints out:

*CMD build "..PATH...\package" --no-resave-data  \ --no-manual*

although I did not specify the *--no-manual*  option in the Build options from RStudio. Additionally, I did not find a way to change this. Might this be the problem?

Can anyone help me with this? I would really appreciate any hints. Please let me know if you need any output or any other information from me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it yourself using:

```
shell('R CMD Rd2pdf . --output=man/figures/manual.pdf --force --no-preview')
```

This will create the PDF and save it to yourpackage/man/figures/manual.pdf.

I use it, so I know it works before I send it to CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. It was really frustrating that it didn't give any error message. But then I tried this:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

Actually I don't really know how it works, but I guess it also install other requirements and now the checking process is done via `devtools` and not directly by `roxygen2`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this was what helped me:
(Im using a Windows computer)

In R-Studio go to "Tools"-->"Project options"-->"Build Tools"
Make a tick at "Generate documentation with Roxygen"

Answer (score -1):

I also come across with this problem, which I think it's a bug of `RStudio`. Try `R CMD check <YOUR PROJECT NAME>` in terminal, in my case, it finally generates an error,

```
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR
Re-running with no redirection of stdout/stderr.
```